# Creating 2D dynamic array inside function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

I know that simillar questions appeard several times but still i can't find excatly this case. I would like to have the function which would create array for futher actions.

```
in main:
    int *field;
    new_field(&field);

void new_field(int **field){    
   int **field = new int*[max_height];
   for (int i = 0; i < max_width; ++i)
      field[i] = new int[max_width];
}
```

"redefinition of formal parameter 'field' " appears, but i tried other options with pointers too :/

Comment: I'd suggest you to use `std::vector` in case you use C++.

Comment: `int **field` you are shadowing you function parameter with a local variable definiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are redefining the `field` variable in your `new_field` function. Just remove the redefinition. This is, change `int** field = ...` for `field = ...` in the `new_field` function.

```
#define max_height 10
#define max_width 10

void new_field(int **field){    
    field = new int*[max_height];
    for (int i = 0; i < max_width; ++i)
        field[i] = new int[max_width];
}
int main(){
    int *field;
    new_field(&field);
}
```

Comment: oh, it was so trivial :c. Thanks!

Comment: If you find this answer correct, please upvote and, if you consider it the right one, please mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the variable field shall have the type `int **`.

Inside the function you redeclare the name field and the compiler reports about this

```
void new_field(int **field){    
   int **field = new int*[max_height];
   //...
```

And in the loop you have to use `max_height` instead of  `max_width`

```
   for (int i = 0; i < max_height; ++i)
```

You can use a referenced type as the parameter. For example

```
int **field;
new_field( field );

//...

void new_field(int ** &field ){    
   field = new int*[max_height];

   for (int i = 0; i < max_height; ++i)
      field[i] = new int[max_width];
}
```

However actually the function allocates several one dimensional arrays.

If the variable `max_width` is a compile time constant then indeed you can allocated a two dimensional array. For example

```
int ( *field }[max_width];
new_field( field );

//...

void new_field(int ( * &field )[max_width] ){    
   field = new int[max_height][max_width];
}
```